# Does Pakistan have the power to force allied foreign troops to leave the country?

Tags: united-states, military, pakistan, funding

Recently President Trump had [criticised Pakistan](https://www.ctvnews.ca/world/in-his-first-tweet-of-2018-trump-slams-pakistan-1.3741329) over the supposed inaction of Pakistan towards terrorists. The funding is a kind of compensation for [military support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_aid_to_Pakistan) in form of bases and other things. Does Pakistan have the legal authority to stop the Coalition Forces, from using their current military bases and order all foreign troops to leave the country?

Comment: Military Power to enforcea decision? Legal power regarding the contracts?
Political Power? Financial Power to make due without Support? What exactly do you mean by "Power"?

Comment: Re "*The funding*": please clarify who is funding what.

Answer (score 2):

> **Does Pakistan have the legal authority to stop the Coalition Forces, from using their current military bases and order all foreign troops to leave the country?**

Pakistan is a sovereign state and its government therefore has the legal right to enact laws and enforce them on its territory. This includes the rights to expel foreign nationals.

Like all such states, Pakistan enters into international treaties with other states. Generally such treaties are regarded as legally binding. Termination of a treaty is likely covered by the terms of the treaty.